# Él ya lo cargó el payaso

Tags: phrase

Would this mean that "He's in big trouble?" I know that "Ya te cargó el payaso" is for the second person, but i'm not sure how the sentence would be formed in the third person. Thank you in advance.

Comment: cargar has many slang meanings. What country is this?? Look at just three of them from the RAE: 44. prnl. coloq. Derrotar o dominar a alguien por la fuerza de la razón.
45. prnl. coloq. matar (‖ quitar la vida). Se cargaron a un delincuente.
46. prnl. coloq. Romper, estropear o anular algo. Your sentence is in the third person: el payaso ya te cargó. It's a subject-verb inversion.

Answer (score 4):

Sólo pretendo dar una respuesta de carácter ‘técnico’, puede ampliar algún mexicano con otra respuesta si considera que a ésta le faltó algo relacionado a la expresión en sí.

- ‘El payaso’: sujeto
- ‘cargó’: verbo
- ‘él’: objeto
- ‘ya’: adverbio

El payaso (**sujeto**) carga **a** alguien (**objeto**). **En general, la preposición ‘a’ suele acompañar al objeto si la acción se realiza sobre una persona**, por más que sea un **objeto directo** como en este caso. Lo correcto es **a** él + **lo**:

> **A** él ya **lo** cargó el payaso.

Y por supuesto que se acepta **omitir el objeto y dejarlo implícito (a través del ‘lo’)** para obtener algo aún más propio del idioma—que es mejor:

> Ya **lo** cargó el payaso.

**ANEXO**

También aclaro que justo en este caso el objeto está en **tercera persona singular masculina (él)**, y por lo tanto excepcionalmente se permite el [**leísmo**](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/leismo-laismo-y-loismo-claves/) (**a** él + **le**), pero no es algo que lo recomiendo para quienes están en la etapa de ‘aprendizaje’.

> ⚠ Ya **le** cargó el payaso.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: Un detalle, me equivoqué con lo de **omitir el sujeto**, en este caso es **omitir el objeto**. Por supuesto es más frecuente lo primero que había dicho pero prestá atención a la diferencia.

Comment: La oración "A él ya lo cargó el payaso"  es  gramaticamente correcto?

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo sería?

Comment: Unos amigos me dijeron que la oración "A él ya se lo cargó el payaso" suena más  natural que "A él ya lo cargó el payaso". Por eso pregunto si es gramaticamente correcto.

Comment: Ambas son válidas, personalmente prefiero la segunda. Si optás por la primera, en ese caso el ‘se’ queda de adorno y no cumple ninguna función gramatical. Algo parecido pasa con ‘no vale’ y ‘no se vale’.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase comes from rodeos. When riders get seriously injured, for example being thrown from a horse or a bull and then trampled, the rodeo clowns cart them out of the arena (or they used to). From this origin you can gather that whoever has been "carried by the clown" is in a pretty bad state - seriously injured or even dead. [Here's an article](https://heraldodemexico.com.mx/cultura/2020/10/28/ya-me-cargo-el-payaso-que-significa-la-frase-popular-mexicana-219279.html) (in Spanish) explaining this etymology of the phrase.

I'd translate "ya (a alguien le) cargó el payaso" colloquially as "(someone's) screwed". "Ya te cargó el payaso" basically means "you're screwed" & it's used in reference to something serious.

It's probably more common to hear the more vulgar "la chingada" instead of "el payaso". "Ya te cargó la chingada" means "you're fucked". This is used in really bad cases up to and including death & can also be used as a serious threat or even a literal death threat to someone - if you do / don't do X "te va a cargar la chingada".

Anyone who's been carried by el payaso or la chingada is in big big trouble, but saying "in big trouble" is not an accurate translation.